# <h:selectOneMenu> in jsf does not display any value in google chrome

Tags: java, jsf, google-chrome

```
<h:selectOneMenu class="medium" id="state" value="#{locationDataBean.stateSelected}" required="true" requiredMessage="Select State">
     <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select State" itemValue="-1"/>
     <f:selectItems value="#{systemResultViewUtil.stateList}"/>
     <a4j:ajax event="change" listener="#{locationServiceBean.retrieveStateDetails()}" render="district,taluka,centerNameList1,stateMsg"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
<h:message for="state" style="color: red" id="stateMsg"/>
```

This is the JSF tag that i have been using and the `value="#{locationDataBean.stateSelected}`" already contains the vlaue from the back bean. but still i dont get a the value selected on the page in chrome. it shows a blank record on the page. the value is obtained on the page and even when i inspect the element it shows the following html script

`<option value="55" selected="selected">466-Assam </option>`
but then also the value is not shown on the page.

Answer (score 0):

If the selectbox HTML looks right yet you cannot see it on the rendered page, maybe your CSS class `medium` is defined to hiding it? Try removing the `class` attribute and see if this has any effect.

Comment: The class attribute didnt had any problems. there were some issues with the javascript setting the value to null after setting the value from backing bean.         
Thank you!!!

Answer (score -1):

Did you try any other browser ?

Try value change listener in h:selectOneMenu element itself like

```
<h:selectOneMenu class="medium" id="state" value="#{locationDataBean.stateSelected}" required="true" requiredMessage="Select State" valueChangeListener="#{locationServiceBean.retrieveStateDetails}">
 <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select State" itemValue="-1"/>
 <f:selectItems value="#{systemResultViewUtil.stateList}"/>
```