# <h:selectOneMenu> not working in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, jsf, cross-browser, richfaces, myfaces

The selectOneMenu tag works fine in IE7 (& above) and Firefox but does not display options in Google Chrome when clicked.

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{action.value}" styleClass="style">        
    <f:selectItems value="#{action.optionList}" />
    <a4j:support event="onchange"
        actionListener="#{action.check}"
        reRender="div" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

Version:
myfaces 1.1.6
richfaces 3.1.1 GA

Answer (score 1):

I've never seen this before, but you're [clearly](http://google.com/search?q=chrome+h:selectonemenu) not the only one having this problem:

- https://community.jboss.org/thread/165008
- https://community.jboss.org/thread/191471
- [<h:selectOneMenu> in jsf does not display any value in google chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12070428/hselectonemenu-in-jsf-does-not-display-any-value-in-google-chrome)
- https://forums.oracle.com/thread/1722455
- http://www.guj.com.br/java/223953-hselectonemenu-nao-funciona-no-chrome
- https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=4425
- etc...

All remains however unanswered, expect of one which seemed to be caused by bad CSS. In any case, ajax is been used to update the dropdown which is likely also true in your specific case. So, my best guess would be that the ajax response contained some Chrome-sensitive syntax error which caused it to fail to properly render the dropdown based on the ajax response. Perhaps it's the `&` character?